# What is better Ubuntu Tweak or Software center?

Tags: software-center, ubuntu-tweak

Ubuntu Tweak has served me very well over the past few release cycles, but there seems to be more and more of an overlap between Ubuntu Tweak and the Ubuntu Software Center.
I wanted to know whether these two great apps are headed for a head-to-head crash (which would be a shame for the Ubuntu community) or is there some way for the two projects to complement each other, integrate and make my favorite distribution even better?

Happy new year to everyone.

Comment: This seems to be very subjective, at best. *Waits for objective answers*

Comment: Tualatrix (Ubuntu Tweak main developer) official answer for a slightly modified (and more objective) question from Launchpad: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/+question/139340

Comment: There are objective answers and I can't see any argumentative ones. So I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 8):

None. They have different uses.

`Ubuntu Tweak` is a Management Tool software, which happens to have an menu for installing **popular** applications. It has menu entrys that allow tweaking windows buttons, cleaning cache and so on. **I personally think that Ubuntu Tweak main focus is allowing easy configuration of the system, not installing apps, and this should be the focus of future versions of it. So yeah, I don't think it'll overlap the functionalities of Ubuntu Software Center.**

`Ubuntu Software Center` is a Application Install Software (front-end to apt-get) which allow you to install/remove **ANY** applications in your computer. **I personally think that Ubuntu Software Center focus is to make easier to install/remove/manage software for your system. I think it's headed to archive a experience of a "Iphone Store" for the Linux Desktop, which we can see as they are trying to synchronize applications installed on the system and pushing payed apps on the Software Center**.

Comment: Ubuntu SC is more a apt-get frontend than a dpkg one, but great comment. You prove Marco wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply misunderstand the purpose of both. Ubuntu-tweak is a tool for modifying multiple areas of your system, where as the software center is for managing software. There is no clash here.

Furthermore Ubuntu-tweak is a 3rd party application.

Comment: Tualatrix (Ubuntu Tweak main developer) official answer for a slightly modified (and more objective) question from Launchad: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/+question/139340